# Python multiprocessing high ram usage even after calling pool.close and pool.join

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

I have to do a parallelization of a code that, reads a line from a parameter file, does some parallelized job and then reads the following line until the file has ended. I did this thing:

```
def unpack(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(arg_tuple):
        return func(*arg_tuple)
    return wrapper

@unpack
def parallel_job(seed,distributioncsv,shift):
    #for each core, create a different file, use different seeds and start
    f = open(distributioncsv,'w+')
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    #number of simulation each core should make
    threadsim = simnum/threadnum
    for i in range (0,threadsim):
          ...do stuff
```

My main is like this: I read the file, loop trough the lines and call multiprocessing. First I define some constants:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #number of simulations, and number of threads to use
    threadnum = 10

    simnum = threadnum*10

    #order in file: Network, N, lambda, gamma, k, i0, tauf, folder
    N_f, lamma_f, gamma_f,k_f, i0_f, tauf_f = np.loadtxt("parameters.txt", delimiter=',', dtype = np.float, usecols =[1,2,3,4,5,6], unpack = True)
    folder_f, networkchoice_f =   np.loadtxt("parameters.txt", delimiter=',', dtype = np.str, usecols =[7,0], unpack = True)

    for i in range(0,len(N_f)):
        #number of nodes
        N = N_f[i]
        #per node infection probability 
        lamma = lamma_f[i]
        #per node recovery probability
        gamma = gamma_f[i]
        #average network degree or number of new links per node
        k = int(k_f[i])
        #initial number of infected nodes
        i0 = int(i0_f[i])
        #tauend of simulations
        tauf = tauf_f[i]
        #folder where to save files
        folder =  os.getenv("HOME")+folder_f[i]
        #Network to simulate
        networkchoice = networkchoice_f[i]

        #where to put the sum of all the distributions
        distributioncsv = folder +"/distribution.csv"

        #where to put all the figures
        destinationofallfigures = folder+"/Figures/a(k)/"
        #file for the k - E(k) values
        akfile = folder+'/csv/E(ak).csv'
        #plot the mean epidemics from simulations (t, I)
        avgepidemics = folder+"/Figures/I(t)/average"
        #columns name
        name = ['I', 'SI', 'deltas','t', 'run']
        saveplots = folder+"/Figures/"
        #file for the mean average
        averagecsv = folder+"/csv/average"

        #different seed for each thread
        seed = [j*2759 + 37*j**2 + 4757 for j in range(threadnum)]
        #to enumerate my runs without loosing track of them   
        shift=[j*simnum for j in range(simnum)]
        #vector with the name of the files to be created
        distribution = [folder+"/csv/distribution_%d.csv" %j for j in range(threadnum)]
```

Here is the relevant part about the parallelization

```
        arguments = zip(seed,distribution,shift)

        #print arguments


        #begin parallelization

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(threadnum)

        #spawn threadnum threads and give them parallel jobs
        pool.map(parallel_job, iterable=arguments)

        pool.close()
        # close the parallelization waiting for all the thread to be done
        pool.join()
        ... do other unparallelized stuff and end the loop
```

Each time a loop ends, I expect a decrease of my memory usage because at some point pool.close() and pool.join() are called.

Instead it happens that loop after loop the memory usage keeps increasing.

Could it be because my parallel_job function has no returning value? 
should I return None at the end of parallel_job? Currently I am not returning anything.

EDIT: I am measuring right now what is the increase of ram usage. Unfortunately the process takes long. Last time I launched this process, after 4 hours it had consumed all the available ram and swap (30 GB) of my pc.

If I launch the unparallelized version of this program, each loop consumes ~3 GB of RAM.

Comment: You should probably include how you measure memory and the actual numbers you see :)